# Make polygons visible in MeshRegions in v11, as they were in v10

Tags: regions, mesh, style

In versions 10.x, polygons in mesh regions were clearly outlines:

[image]

In version 11.0 they aren't by default.

[image]

How do I get back the v10 display so I can see where my polygons are, even in flat faces such as in `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cuboid[]]`?

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using the `PlotTheme -> "Default"`.  I couldn't find this in the documentation so I though it would be useful to share.

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Ball[], PlotTheme -> "Default"]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `PlotTheme -> "Default"` also works.

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks!  This should really be documented.  Remember that other question I asked about meshes that you answered?  This is why I kept setting the `MeshCellStyle`.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're saying. I found this theme with the autocomplete feature.

Comment: @ChipHurst THank you, I corrected it.  Invalid values also restore the default, so "SmallMesh" is probably wrong.  I removed it.